# Ctrl+F (find) is not working as expected on certain websites in Firefox

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I'm (now) using Firefox 89.0 (64-bit) for Ubuntu, but this issue has existed for a long time when using Firefox on Ubuntu.

I'm having an issue with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (the find feature) in Firefox. Mostly it works fine, but on some websites (for example [this one](https://pub.ist.ac.at/%7Emkwan/publications.html)), it just doesn't work at all (the find bar comes up, but when I type words into it that exist on the page, it doesn't locate them for me).

When I restart Firefox in troubleshoot mode it works, which made me think it might be an issue with an extension, but when I disable my extensions one-by-one it doesn't seem to fix it. What else might be causing this issue?

Comment: Are you sure `Mach Case`, `Match Diacritics` and `Whole Words` current options are not conflicting with the expected search result?